# Invisible bubbles in nvd3 scatter chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have this scatter chart and a sample data. For some reason, I see bubbles that are invisible / not shown. Y axis (at 6) and many more points. Am I doing something wrong or its some bug ?

```
nv.addGraph(function () {

var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
    .showDistX(true) //showDist, when true, will display those little distribution lines on the axis.
.showDistY(true)
    .transitionDuration(350)
    .color(['#1f77b4'])
    .margin({
    left: 150,
    right: 150
})
    .showLegend(false)
    .sizeRange([50, 5000])
    .interactive(true);

//Configure how the tooltip looks.
chart.tooltipContent(function (key) {
    return '<center><b>Value</b><br><h3>' + key + '</h3></center>';
});


chart.forceY(0)

//Axis settings
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
    return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(d));
});
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
    return d;
});

//We want to show shapes other than circles.
chart.scatter.onlyCircles(true);

d3.select('#categories-viewed-scatterchart svg')
    .datum(data)
    .call(chart);

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

return chart;
});
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eyedagger/4Dm9D/

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Where are these invisible bubbles that are shown?

Comment: Just hover on the y(6) and you will see tooltips. But no bubbles to represent them.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the way I was storing data was the issue. I had a key for each dataset, I was supposed to have unique keys for a group of datasets.

Looks like if keys are duplicated, the issue arises.